# Discord.js v12 Trying to make a 'guess the number' game

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to code the 'guess the number' game. This is my code:

```js
if (message.content === `${Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1}`) {
 const channel = message.client.channels.cache.get('755124858744078468');
 const Member = message.channel.guild.roles.cache.get('725350761751511061');
 const rightEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setColor('DARK_GREEN')
  .setTitle(`${message.author.username} got the right number!`)
  .setTimestamp()
  .setFooter('PlanetMc Development');
 message.channel.send({ embed: rightEmbed });
 console.log(`${message.author.username} got the right number!`);
 channel.updateOverwrite(Member, { SEND_MESSAGES: false });
 message.channel.send('&reload guess');
}
```

But it's not working, and not returning any errors. I should have got the message because I tried every number between 1 and 6.

Comment: Did you get any error?

Comment: Nope. the problem must be something in here: ```if (message.content === `${Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1}`) {```

Comment: @Zeroknights how do you know the problem is within the `if` statement? What does it do and what should it do?

Comment: I'm not that new to discord.js and the other 'commands' are basic ones. So I'm pretty sure that the rest is working. The ```if``` statement should get you a random number between 1 and 6.

Comment: You can try every number between one and six and it still not trigger, but still be working. Since it's a new random number every time, it could've just been generating numbers like this, for example: `6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5`.

Comment: You're generating a new random everytime theres a message, try store `${Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1}` in a variable and compare it to `message.content`.

Answer (score -1):

The thing is that whenver there is a message the `Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1` resets.

This means that it will generate a new number whenver the client.on('message') is emitted.

You should choose whether to use [a message collector](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html) or a database to stock the current number for the guild. You have the choice